# R Histogram: Binning by one characteristic, Density by another

Tags: r, histogram

I have a data frame of two variables, x and y in R. What i want to do is bin each entry by its value of x, but then display the density of the value of y for all entries in each bin. More specifically, for each interval in units of x, i want to plot the sum(of all values of y of entries whose values of x are in the specific interval)/(sum of all values of y for all entries). I know how to do this manually via vector manipulation, but i have to make a lot of these plots and wanted to know if their was a quicker way to do this, maybe via some advanced hist.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the groupings using `cut` and then use a `facet_grid` to display the multiple histograms:

```
# Sample data with y depending on x
set.seed(144)
dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000))
dat$y <- dat$x + rnorm(1000)

# Generate bins of x values
dat$grp <- cut(dat$x, breaks=2)

# Plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=y)) + geom_histogram() + facet_grid(grp~.)
```

[image]